# When TextView set android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp" and set drawableRight，then the text and image not on a horizontal line

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="just is test"
    android:textColor="@color/light_black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:drawableRight="@id/item_avatar"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="18dp" />
```

The text and image not on a horizontal line.

the android:gravity="center_vertical" and padding dons't work.

This bothers me for a long time,How to solve it ? Thank you.

Comment: post your whole xml...

Comment: the xml only have TextView

Comment: u mensioned image in ur question?

Comment: image is ok,i know my problem,thank you for your answer.